# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings' after fresh anaconda install

Tags: windows, anaconda

Recently my anaconda completely broke and I tried to reinstall it. I was having this error prior to the new installation and thought a fresh install might fix it. However, after the install the same error message persists. I am unable to start up an anaconda console and get this error message every time. I have seen suggestions about changing pythonhome and path, but it doesnt really seem to apply in this case as I have checked and made 100% sure they are correct. Any other suggestions?

[image: The Error]

I have tried a fresh install to no avail. I have changed pathing settings based on previous post and that does not seem to fix the issue.